# How can I access ViewData in a PartialView from jQuery in MVC?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

I have a View loading a PartialView via jQuery. The PartialView has ViewData that the jQuery needs to access, but I can't seem to get to it from the jQuery. The code below uses the HighChart jQuery plugin (and it is just test code taken from the HighChart example page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var chart1; // globally available
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#reportButton').click(function (event) {
                var actionUrl = '<%= Url.Action("UserReport") %>';
                var customerId = $('#customersId').val();
                var month = $('#monthsId').val();
                var employees = '<%= ViewData["Employees"] %>'
                alert(employees);
                $.get(actionUrl, { customerId: customerId, month: month }, function (data) {
                    $('#result').html(data);
                    getHighChart();
                });
            });
        });

        function getHighChart() {
            var employees = '<%= ViewData["Employees"] %>'
            alert(employees);
            chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'chart-container-1',
                    defaultSeriesType: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Fruit Consumption'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: [employees]
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fruit eaten'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Jane',
                    data: [1, 0, 4]
                }, {
                    name: 'John',
                    data: [5, 7, 3]
                }]
            });
        }


    </script>
```

This jQuery is in the main view, because I don't know how I could put it in the PartialView with the document ready function. But by putting the call to the HighChart function in the callback of the get() function it works in the partial view. But accessing the ViewData doesn't...

How can I achieve this? I need to get the data from the PartialView action method in order to populate the HighChart data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the way ASP.NET traverses the HTML document when rendering.

Even though you have this code executing after the `$.get` call has finished:

```
var employees = '<%= ViewData["Employees"] %>'
```

The `ViewData` property will get evaluated *render-time* (e.g before this code is executed).

**What i recommend:**

Declare a hidden field in your partial view, and place the `ViewData` in there:

```
<input type="hidden" id ="Employees_ViewData" value="<%: ViewData["Employees"] %>" />
```

That will get evaluated *when the partial view is rendered*.

Then you can access it via jQuery:

```
var employees = $('#Employees_ViewData').val();
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked in as much as I can now get the data to the jQuery. However, it turns out doing it like this doesn't get me the data in the right form apparently. My idea was to create a string in the controller (basically ViewData["Employees"] = "'Joe', 'Jane'" but created in a loop) and pass it to the View. But that only got me a strange string in the chart... So how do I get the data into the highchart parameter in the correct form? ( categories: ['Jane', 'Joe'] )?

Comment: not sure, i don't know much about the highchart plugin. but it sounds like you need to serialize the data into JSON.